# Is it possible to intercept Google Recaptcha answer-response via Wireshark?

Tags: c++, networking, wireshark, libpcap

I'm using PolarProxy for decrypting HTTPS requests.

When I look at intercepted response from Recaptcha, I see pretty strange payload

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC9ux.png)

It is HTTP2 protocol.

As you can see, cookies are the same, it means we a looking at the same requests, but response in Wireshark is completely different from response in browser. Why?

Does anyone know how to intercept that response from Recaptcha?

I want to do it in C++ (libpcap) in future, but first I want to do it manually.

Comment: Its a cookie, I don't imagine its value is documented

Comment: Cookie says that we are looking at the same request. The problem is that decrypted response in Wireshark differs from the response in browser. I don't know why....

Comment: HTTP2 responses are typically sent as a separate payload/packet, which is why you cannot see the response payload of the response in the same packet as the HTTP2 response headers. Try looking at the next HTTP2 packet in the capture file and you'll see the payload of the response.